# D language Socket.receive()

Tags: sockets, d

I wrote a socket server using D on Windows and now I want to port it on Linux. Here is code summary:

```
/*
 * this.rawsocks - SocketSet
 * this.server - Socket
 * this.clients - array of custom client worker class
 */

char[1] buff;
string input;
int nbuff = 0;

while (this.isrun) {
    this.rawsocks.add(this.server);

    if (Socket.select(this.rawsocks, null, null)) {
        if (this.rawsocks.isSet(this.server)) {
            // accepting a new connection
        }

        foreach (ref key, item; this.clients) {
            // works for all connections
            writeln("test1");

            // mystically interrupts foreach loop
            nbuff = item.connection.receive(buff);

            // works only for the first connection.
            // when the first connection is closed, it works for the next
            writeln("test2");
        }
    }

    this.rawsocks.reset();

    foreach (key, value; this.clients)
        this.rawsocks.add(value.connection);
}
```

`item.connection.receive(buff)` works fine on Windows, but interrupts foreach loop on Linux. There are no any exceptions, and `test2` for next client is firing when first client is disconnected.

Is there some specially behaviour of `.receive()` method in Linux, or there are some problems in my implementation?

Comment: What do you mean by `'interrupts foreach loop'`?

Comment: @vines I ment that calling of `.receive()` for next client breaks the `foreach` loop

Comment: It looks like a serious bug in the compiler... Which one you use, by the way?

Comment: @vines I use **dmd 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this problem is as strange as the problem itself :)

```
foreach (ref key, item; this.clients) {
     /*
      * The solution
      * Check of client's socket activity in SocketSet queue may not be necessary in Windows, but it is necessary in Linux
      * Thanks to my friend's research of this problem
      */
     if (!this.rawsocks.isSet(item.connection)) continue;

     // works for all connections
     writeln("test1");

     // after modifying not interrupts foreach loop
     nbuff = item.connection.receive(buff);

     // after modifying also works for all connections
     writeln("test2");
}
```

Comment: Random guess: Maybe a posix signal is sent to your process if you try to call receive on a socket without activity. But this should kill the whole process, not only the foreach loop...